# How to find the peak memory usage in a maven build

Tags: java, maven

I need to find out the peak memory usage of a `maven` build, can I rely on the final output given by successful `maven` build. Does `43M` indicates the peak memory usage during the `maven` build. Thanks in advance.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.222 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-07-31T19:10:04+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 43M/636M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here :

```
Final Memory: 43M/636M
```

`43M` is the used memory and `636M` the current allocated memory (heap size) by the JVM at the end of the build.
But these information could not give you the peak value.

Why the used memory (`43M`) cannot be considered as the peak ?

- Because the peak may have occurred before the end of the build.

Why the heap size (`636M`) cannot be considered as the peak ?

- Because the peak may be superior to the heap size if the GC reduced the heap size between the peak and the end of the build .
  It may be the case for a very long build that performs intensive tasks at the beginning and lighter tasks then.
- Because the peak may be inferior to the heap size if the GC has increased the heap size until this value but the application never needs to consume as much as memory.

To get the memory peak during the execution of the maven build, monitor the Java application (maven execution) with any JVM tool designed for : JVisualVM or JConsole for example.

Here's an screenshot of a maven build of a Spring Boot application monitored by JVisualVM  that shows that neither the heap size or the used size at the end of build are the peak value :

[image]

Comment: `JVisualVM` is the best as it can be used to monitor several processes at once. And when running the `maven` build, make sure to open(double click) the relevant processes generated under the `Application` window of the `JVisualVM`  as the build processes are killed once after the built is completed making you unable to monitor the process. By opening the relevant process before it is being killed, will allow to monitor the build process well.

Comment: Yes, and if you have e.g. unit tests, the surefire plugin starts parallel an additional process without using MAVEN_OPTS for that.

Comment: Hey, can you please recommend any tool to do monitoring in the CLI?